# Uploading files to GLPI server POST_MAX_SIZE

Tags: c#, rest, api, file-upload

I'm trying to POST a Document (any file type) to a GLPI server through API REST.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var rcontent = string.Empty;
            // HEADERS (URL + Access Tokens)

            //string _ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            string _Uri = Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_URL + "/Document/";

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_Uri);
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Session-Token", Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_SESSION_TOKEN);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("App-Token", Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_APP_TOKEN);

            // JSON Content (input string array with file uploaded informations)

            JSON_C.DocumentAdder JSONContent = new JSON_C.DocumentAdder();
            JSONContent.name = "sth";
            JSONContent._filename = filebytes;
            HttpContent _JSONContent = new StringContent("uploadManifest={\"input\": " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONContent).ToString() + "}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Add(_JSONContent);

            // File Content in bytes
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(filebytes);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("_filename") { FileName = filepath };
            //fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            content.Add(fileContent);

            // Request
            HttpResponseMessage reponse;
            var _Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
            reponse = client.PostAsync(_Uri, content).Result;

            // Request response
            rcontent = reponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            textBox2.Text = reponse.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + rcontent.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what I got in response:

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>      Connection: close
>      Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
>      Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 12:50:09 GMT
>      Server: Apache/2.4.29
>      Server: (Ubuntu)
>      Content-Length: 61
>      Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>      Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GM
>   }

With:

> ["ERROR_UPLOAD_FILE_TOO_BIG_POST_MAX_SIZE","The file seems too big"]

The file I'm trying to upload is 592bytes! Max overall limit in one request is 2Mo. And `post_max_size` in php.ini is "8M", the same result after I changed it to "0" (for no limit at all). And then set it to 20M to match `upload_max_filesize`  (/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini).
`upload_max_filesize`_.. is also "20M"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone finding this post and needs help, here is how i managed to succeed :
After separatly creating a "Session-Token", and using "RestSharp".

```
// Upload

var RSClient = new RestClient(Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_URL);

var request = new RestRequest("Document", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Session-Token", Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_SESSION_TOKEN);
request.AddHeader("App-Token", Properties.Settings.Default.GLPI_APP_TOKEN);
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddQueryParameter("uploadManifest", "{\"input\": {\"name\": \"UploadFileTest\", \"_filename\": \"GiletsJaunes.jpg\"}}");
request.AddFile("test", @"C:\path\to\File.jpg");

IRestResponse response = RSClient.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;

textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + content;
```

Details :

- I couldn't use `RestSharp.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator` for some reasons, so i added these Auth params with `AddHeader`.
- I couldn't use a Serialised Json string in a `new StringContent`, because of `AddQueryParameter`, so i wrote it manually.

Alleluyah.